# Netbeans & Maven: different compilation behavior

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans

I am using Netbeans and Maven projects.
In some case Netbeans show me compilation failures (red ballon) BUT Maven compile everything without any problem!

What can be the reason of this difference.
I already checked that both are using the same JDK version.

Comment: Well, what are the compilation failures? Netbeans uses Ant to build its projects so you could just read the Ant file to see what is going on when your projects are built. Or, you could switch your Maven scripts to Ant and then you can use the same script regardless of whether you're building from within Netbeans or not.

Comment: Where to find the Ant file used by Netbeans?

Comment: Look for the build-impl.xml file in your nbproject directory.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason could be that you have not added the required jar in your net beans class path. But the jar is being listed in your maven pom.xml

Comment: You can provide some more information or atleast putthe errors details

Comment: When using a Maven project, we cannot set classpath for the netbeans project properties... Maven integration makes netbeans compile with all jar specified in the dependencies in the pom.xml

Did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, do an `mvn install` once from your command line in your project directory, and then re-open or reload the project in your netbeans IDE (I hope you are using 6.9?).

This will install all the artifacts in your local repo.

This usually happens if you have modules in your maven project and they depend on each other.

Comment: It is exactly how I work (maven called through command line or through nbactions)... And whatever I open/re-open projects, netbeans show me errors not raised by Maven.

Everything happen like Netbeans and Maven do not use the same JDK or compile options...

Answer (score 0):

some more details would be needed for more in-depth analysis.

In most cases a difference in compilation errors between cmdline and netbeans editor can be caused by missing source roots (read generated source roots - see the project properties Sources panel on how to setup source roots).

netbeans is embedding an old svn HEAD snapshot maven binaries so in some very rare cases there could be differences in resolving the dependency tree, but I have yet to see such case.

also the netbeans compiler doesn't pick up most of the switches defined on the compiler plugin
apart from target/source, encoding.

The netbeans editor compiler is not 100% compatible with jdk compiler and there have been cases of incompatibilities so we are back to the need to see the actual errors first..