# Maven Eclipse Indigo Plugin weird/inconsistant results

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have just imported a maven project into eclipse indigo which seems bundled with an existing maven plugin.
Eclipse project files where generated using .project/.classpath using the separate command mvn eclipse:eclipse.

Then trying to run "maven install" from the IDE lead to "BUILD SUCCESSFULL" in eclipse console... but the eclipse editors show inconsistant compile errors in some few java file, such a "The import my.package.class could not be resolved" whereas it mentions a class from the same project, with no compile error mentionned by the IDE.

Anyone encountered such problems?

Changing property "Maven" > "Installations" > "Embeddable 3.xx" to "External path/to/maven" did not changed anything.

To be able to run maven, I changed eclipse.ini to target the JDK's JRE (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre)

Maven installation is @ version 2.2.1 on my computer.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in Indigo you should never use mvn eclispe:eclipse anymore cause that's handled by m2e instead...Furthermore i would suggest to upgrade to Maven 3.0. cause in Eclipse you are using already an Maven 3.0.X ...Have you checked on command line if

```
mvn clean package
```

is succesful without any error message...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. clean+package do not change anything. We have some maven error reading 2.x pom files with 3.x so for the moment we keep 2.x. By the way, we have the same problems on netbeans that is also pointed by other users: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3455958/229513

Comment: This can't be cause they use the same model...Can you post the error message which you have ?

Comment: I finally stopped using maven for dev. I hate the integration into both eclipse and netbeans that hang each time maven decide to do something, whereas maven "forget to build" stuff when I save files. I go for eclipse projects + ant, and maybe IVY for dependency management, but maven must remain on a build server, no in a developper IDE. In dev, we only keep project layout src/main/java and the like which is a good idea.

Comment: You wrote you give up using Maven but you didn't answer my question about the error message...it sounds you don't have much experience with Maven...But blaming Maven for the problems you have. Not updating etc. furthermore what does "forget to build" mean ? What would you like to achieve...? Maven is not only dependency management...

Comment: "forget to build" means that when project A has a dependency to project B, I need to manually ask to rebuild project B to have project A get changes in project B.

Comment: Do you have those projects in Eclipse? Are those project within a multi-module build or are these projects independant? Have you turned on solve project dependencies in Eclipse ?

Comment: Yes we had these projects bundled in a multi module build. I haven't found the option you mentionned in Eclipse preferences.

Comment: You can select a project right mouse button -> Properties -> Resolve dependencies from Workspace project (which should be turned on usually). Can you give the pom's (maybe an excerpt) so i can take a look into it ..(pastebin?)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8123/discussion-between-martin-and-khmarbaise)